# How to write correctly the term "User experience"?

Tags: terminology, users, experience, grammar

I'm filling an user experience portfolio for my business and there is bagarre how to write "user experience" correctly.

The terms now inserted are much fragmented like:

- User eXperience
- user experience
- User Experience

Do you know some grammar correct rule for this term? Thank you

Comment: It's 'User experience' or 'user experience'. Some would suggest the use of 'UX' as an acronym however that is dependant on the tone of your portfolio.

Comment: more one for English SE.
To me any is right. user experience if you're just on about UX in general,  User experience if it begins a sentence and is general, User Experience if its a title, User eXperience if you want to show why it is called UX (or you're from the 1990s and think Xs are cool and Xtreme)

Comment: You're lucky that the only thing you're arguing about is the spelling instead of actually having it present in your company :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### English can be a challenge

#### Capitalisation

This is a stylistic choice. If you use Initial Capitalisation for all job titles, for example, on a résumé or cv, then it's User Experience. It's rare to use sentence capitalisation for job titles on a résumé or CV, but if you do, then it's User experience.

If you are talking about a matter of user experience in a sentence, such as this one, then it's lower case. Of course, you capitalise the first word of a sentence.

#### Hyphenation

When the words "user experience" modify a noun and are placed *BEFORE* the noun, it takes a hyphen. All of these are correct:

- I work in user-experience design.
- A user-experience question is always interesting.
- This is a matter of user experience.

**[Edit]** A few of the comments suggest you must not hyphenate. What they're advising is to disregard the rules of English grammar, simply because many of us are not familiar with the rule or do not apply it. There's an argument to be made for this, since language can and does evolve. I'm inclined to use the published rules of grammar and spelling, and to correct my errors when I notice them. :)

#### Combining the two is simple

Hyphenation is separate from your choice of capitalisation. So these are also correct:

- I work as a User-Experience Designer.
- A user-experience question is always interesting.
- We call this team by a rather straight-forward name: Team User Experience.

—

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I've never seen it hyphenated, but sure, why not? :)

Comment: Do not hyphenate the term unless you intend to look like an outsider. If you're on this site, you probably don't want that.

Answer (score 5):

## General use

There's nothing special about the two words that requires capitalization. In general usage it would look like this:

> We can pour **user experience** awesomesauce on your product because we outsource to Ukranian **user experience** designers and mark up their work 1000%!

In the latter instance, you may choose to formalize the title with capitalization:

> Hire our Ukranian **User Experience** Designers and get a free iPod.

## Industry speak

When you're speaking to an insider audience, UX or UXD has become shorthand for *user experience design*. Sometimes it actually represents interaction design (IxD) or (worse) graphic design. But only the purists among us seem to be concerned with such semantics.

> Skillz: SEO, Flash, Banner Ads, **UX**, Branding

Or you can [accurately] distinguish the design aspect (vs research):

> Mo skillz: UX Mumbo Jumbo, UX Research, **UX Design**

## Recruiter-friendly

Industry buzz words and insider speak (like acronyms) almost always earn bonus points with recruiters. Since you'd typically be trying to show up in a search, it's best to cover your bases with a little redundancy.

> You should hire me because I do **User Experience Design (UXD)**, Interaction Design (IxD), Information Architecture (IA), and Pseudo Design (PxD).

Consider your résumé powered up!

[image: Mario earns mega points!]

## Do-not-hyphenate-!!!

In spite of the fuzzy rules of the English language, **do not hyphenate the terms under any circumstances.** Unless you're applying for an English professor position. Then you want to check with [another SE site](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

User Experience

thats how ive always seen it written

If I saw User eXperience on a CV I would think you're a pretentious idiot.

Comment: I don't know about pretentious, but definitely obnoxious.